# Custom fonts not showing

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I have added new fonts to my `app/assets/fonts/NewFont` folder.

I have also added font files there: `1234.eot`,  `1234.woff2`, `1234.woff`, `1234.ttf`

In my `fonts.scss.css` I have added:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'NewFont';
  src: font-url('NewFont/1234.eot');
  src: font-url('NewFont/1234.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       font-url('NewFont/1234.woff2') format('woff2'),
       font-url('NewFont/1234.woff') format('woff'),
       font-url('NewFont/1234.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

And when I use it for my body:

```
html, body {
  font-family: 'NewFont',  sans-serif;
}
```

And nothing happens. My font on the web-site is still showing the same. **What am I missing?**

I am using `Ubuntu`, but this shouldn't be dependent on the system in any-case.

I have tried replacing the `font-url` with `assets-url`, but no luck.

Should the `font-family` match some kind of font family that is already defined in the font files?

`config/initializers/assets.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(1234.eot
                                                 1234.ttf
                                                 1234.woff
                                                 1234.woff2
                                                 fonts.css.scss)
```

Comment: Are you fonts and css listed on `config/initializers/assets.rb`?

Comment: Hm, no, but I have now tried to add it, and after restarting the server nothing changed.

Comment: can you first check your dev tool to verify if the fonts are loaded or for any errors ? Font issues can easily be spotted with Dev tools

Comment: Is the element you are trying to have that font-family actually using it? Maybe it has an override by another css rule

Comment: Yes, it is using. If I add a font to my system folder in Ubunty `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/NewFont/1234.ttf` it is showing the new font. (I have added `assets.rb` to the question). Console also doesn't show an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that I forgot to require the `fonts` file itself to the `application.css` file at the very top of the file:

```
 *= require fonts
```

**Side note:**

Make sure that the fonts are in the public folder so production web-site can pick the fonts. For that purpose, update the:

```
src: font-url('NewFont/1234.eot')
```

to

```
src: url('/fonts/NewFont/1234.eot')
```

(in case you have moved the new font to the `public/fonts/` directory)

Answer (score 0):

You need to link to your assets  folder:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: '1234';
    src: url('assets/fonts/NewFont/1234.eot');
    ...
    ...

}
```

More info on `asset_path` here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: It didn't work (although I think `font-path` is not needed)

Comment: Edited for a simpler fix

Comment: I don't think the issue is in the location of the font, but in the name of the `font-family`. My font doesn't have any specification in it. I think the issue is there. I am investigating it currently. (the change didn't help)